# RStudio V0.99.441 - no leading or trailing or multiple spaces in View?

Tags: r, rstudio

Reinstalled `RStudio` and `R` (`R` 3.2.0) and found out that `RStudio` (Version 0.99.441) Viewer strips leading, trailing, and multiple spaces from strings. They all are critical in my project and should be visible. Here's an example:

```
qqq = " test one space  two space   three space "
View(qqq)
```

Result:
[image]

In addition, it's not possible to copy/paste the View with the column names anymore, only the data frame itself can be copied from the Viewer. Or the headers but w/o the first (empty) box where the `row.numbers` should have been - this results in shifted headers in pasted content.

Example:

[image]

Is there a box in Options I haven't marked? Thanks!
Note: both features worked with previous RStudio (cannot tell the version at this time)

Comment: Are you talking about the RStudio View?

Comment: It is possible, and I think this has nothing to do with `R` version. You need to use `mouse` to copy and paste.

Comment: I did use the mouse.

Comment: If it was working with a previous version of RStudio, you should report it.

Comment: Both features worked. I don't know the previous RStudio version, as my main work laptop is being repaired and I'm using a spare one, where I had to install from scratch - thus got R 3.2.0 and RStudio V0.99.441

Comment: It is definitively not an R issue.

Comment: OK. R tag removed. Question clarified

Comment: Move mouse such that you are going upward toward column names.

Comment: I tried all possible directions before posting the question.

Comment: @Pascal - how do I report it? Thanks!